# How to create properties without white spaces between separator using org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration?

Tags: java, properties-file

Need to write a properties file using org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration and it should have a format like **variablename=variablevalue** without having whitespaces between the separator. Is there a way to achieve that using apache commons-configuration?

My current implementation :

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("test.properties");
conf.setProperty("key1","value1");
conf.save();
```

Result :

```
key1 = value1
```

Expected Result :

```
key1=value1
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you need that because while reading back it will be read as key-value pair only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs are here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_properties.html

Untested but I imagine this does it:

```
conf.getLayout().setGlobalSeparator("=");
```